# Reverse Proxy/Forward HTTP Requests in Erlang

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, erlang

I have searched the web and found inets and mod_esi, however I need to build a module that takes a HTTP request to `http://localhost:8000` and then reverse proxies it to `http://localhost:9000` without doing a HTTP forward, as I need the proxied server to be anonymous to the requester at all times.

Something similar implemented in Node.JS can be found: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The [Yaws web server](http://yaws.hyber.org/) supports both forward and reverse proxies. Maybe you can have a look at the [Yaws source code](https://github.com/klacke/yaws) for inspiration.